# What do i do when my windows service crashes and doesnt restart

Tags: c#, windows, debugging, service, crash

My windows service crashes at random times and doesn't restart automatically. When it crashes in the services, it shows that it's running but my program doesn't do anything. I can't debug it because it's a service and happens at random times. There are two error messages at event viewer about it.

First one is **.NetRuntime** error

> Application: MyProgramService.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: exception code eedfade, exception address 77935A12
> Stack:

Second error is Application Error:

> Faulting application name: MyProgramService.exe, version: 2.23.600.0, time stamp: 0x64b8dea8
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.17763.4720, time stamp: 0xd343834f
> Exception code: 0x0eedfade
> Fault offset: 0x00125a12
> Faulting process id: 0x1f4c
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d9d671bfba5afd
> Faulting application path: C:\PMP007\MyProgramService.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
> Report Id: 38d6179c-f75b-4310-94da-24ae53643627
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID: `

My first thought was **.Net** library was faulty. So, I tried my program on some other test server and this time there was only one Application error at event viewer.

> Faulting application name: MyProgramService.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x9c0a1bab
> Faulting module name: combase.dll, version: 10.0.17763.4377, time stamp: 0x567c9399
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
> Fault offset: 0x0009e352
> Faulting process id: 0x26cc
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d9d4bef06d9156
> Faulting application path: C:\PMP_TEST\MyProgramService.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
> Report Id: ecca6f82-b115-4557-b0e9-54a2cb3eaaa2
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:`

This time when service crashed, it restarted itself and continued to work but how can find problem at the first server I tried.

Comment: Add try/catch to your methods, add logs to the catch blocks. Read the logs to undestand where it crashes. Fix the error. Repeat.

Comment: EEDFADE (you can search web) is a ADelphi exception.  From what I found it look like an access exception.  Services by default is run with a System Account which does not have Environmental.  Try starting service with a Service Account that has an environment.

Comment: I checked local security policy policy and my user was added in Log on as a service section. In the meantime i will ad catch block to my code